# Using user input to fill 2D String array with a prompt-Java

Tags: java, arrays

Here's my code, my problem is that after I enter the values for rowNum and colNum, it displays the "Please enter a value" prompt twice and fills the first part w/ a space it seems like. Help would be appreciated!

```
import java.util.*;

public class Lab11 {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        // A scanner object for requesting input from the user
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        // An integer for the number of rows.
        int rowNum;
        // An integer for the number of columns.
        int colNum;
        //a string search for the string to search for
        String search;

     // Print this message "Enter the number of rows in the array" //
        System.out.print("Enter the number of rows in the array" );
        rowNum = scan.nextInt();
     // Print this message "Enter the number of columns in the array //
        System.out.print("Enter the number of columns in the array");
        colNum = scan.nextInt();
     // Use the scanner to store the values entered by the user
     // in the integers declared above.

     // Declare a 2D String array using the number of rows and columns previously entered by the user
     String[][] stringArray = new String[rowNum][colNum];

     for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++){
         for (int j = 0; j < stringArray[i].length; j++){
             System.out.println("Please enter a value");
             stringArray[i][j] = scan.nextLine();
         }
     }

     for (int ii = 0; ii < stringArray.length; ii++){
           for (int jj = 0; jj < stringArray[ii].length; jj++){
               System.out.print(stringArray[ii][jj]+" ");
           }
           System.out.println();
     }

     System.out.println("Please enter the string you are searching for");
     search = scan.nextLine();
     for (int iii = 0; iii < stringArray.length; iii++){
         for (int jjj = 0; jjj < stringArray[iii].length; jjj++){
             if(stringArray[iii][jjj].equals(search)){
                 System.out.println("Element found at position ("+iii+","+jjj+")");
             }
         }
     }



    }

}
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13102066/1552587

Comment: Something different to your question, you might want to change the way you comment your code. Comments are for clarification. What you do is essentially repeat the line of code - "An integer for the number of columns", int colNum. In this case, it is completely clear from the name of the variable for what it stands, doesn't require a comment. Use comments when something is not obvious, like before a big block of code that does strange stuff. In your code, you can basically delete all comments.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because the `scan.nextInt();` method does not consume the last newline character of your input, and thus that newline is consumed in the next call to `scan.nextLine` so you need to use like this way `Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());` here we are doing typecasting and using `nextLine()` method instead of `nextInt()`. and scan is object of Scanner class.

So, I modified your code it is working fine,

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int rowNum;
        int colNum;
        String search;

        System.out.print("Enter the number of rows in the array");
        rowNum = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        System.out.print("Enter the number of columns in the array");
        colNum = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

        String[][] stringArray = new String[rowNum][colNum];

        for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < stringArray[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a value");
                stringArray[i][j] = scan.nextLine();
            }
        }

        for (int ii = 0; ii < stringArray.length; ii++) {
            for (int jj = 0; jj < stringArray[ii].length; jj++) {
                System.out.print(stringArray[ii][jj] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println("Please enter the string you are searching for");
        search = scan.nextLine();
        for (int iii = 0; iii < stringArray.length; iii++) {
            for (int jjj = 0; jjj < stringArray[iii].length; jjj++) {
                if (stringArray[iii][jjj].equals(search)) {
                    System.out.println("Element found at position (" + iii + "," + jjj + ")");
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```